# Can we classify all functions whose gradient is an eigenvector of the Hessian?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hessian-matrix, scalar-fields

Let's treat the case of two dimensions, then we don't have freedom with the other eigenvector. Is there any classification of all smooth functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $\nabla f$ is an eigenvector of $D^2f$ at every point? Such functions solve a second-order quasilinear PDE, but makes me wonder if there is a reference with a more "explicit" classification.

Comment: If you assume the eigenvalues are constants, you can integrate to get that $$2\lambda f + C = |\nabla f|^2$$ However, the eigenvalues may be functions themselves.

Comment: Thank you, I agree this is the case with constant eigenvalues but it might be too much to ask for constant eigenvalues.

Comment: If $\nabla^2 f(x) \nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla f(x)$, then, by taking scalar product with $\nabla f(x)$ on both sides and using one of the possible definitions of the [infinity Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Laplacian), we either get $\Delta_{\infty} f (x) = \lambda |\nabla f(x)|^2$ or $\Delta_{\infty} f (x) = \lambda$. Seems like a cool connection to your question

Comment: The isosurfaces of these functions seem to be parallel but not equidistant hyperplanes.

Comment: @jokersobak: If I understood correctly you mean such functions can only be affine, I am not sure if that is correct. If we take $f(x,y)=1/2(x^2+y^2)$, then the Hessian is the identity matrix and hence every vector is an eigenvector by $D^2f$ in particular the gradient.